# Javascript not submitting data to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

Hello I am a newbie to all these forms and php and javascript.
I just made some modifications to this code. But I can't make it run a php file.
I don't know why? Please help. It ran successfully before my modifications.

The javascript function for sending data to sendotp.php

```
function send_otp(){
    var mobile=jQuery('#mobile').val();
    var email=jQuery('#email').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'sendotp.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{'mobile='+mobile,'email='+email}
        success:function(result){
            if(result=='1'){
                jQuery('.second_box').show();
                jQuery('.first_box').hide();
            }
            if(result=='not_exist'){
                jQuery('#email_error').html('Please enter valid mobile or E-mail');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The javascript function for checking otp is

```
function submit_otp(){
    var otp=jQuery('#otp').val();
    var eotp=jQuery('#eotp').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'checkotp.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{'otp='+otp,'eotp='+eotp},
        success:function(result){
            if(result=='yes'){
                window.location='savedata.php'
            }
            if(result=='Please enter correct otp.'){
                jQuery('#otp_error').html('Please enter valid otp');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The html code is

```
<div class="login-form">
<form  method="post">
    <h2 class="text-center">Alumni Authorization</h2>       
    <div class="form-group first_box">
        <input type="text" id="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="10 Digit Mobile No" required="required">
        <span id="email_error" class="field_error"></span>
        <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter E-mail" required="required">
        <span id="email_error" class="field_error"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group first_box">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="send_otp()">Send OTP</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group second_box">
        <input type="text" id="otp" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile OTP" required="required">
        <span id="otp_error" class="field_error"></span>
        <input type="text" id="eotp" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail OTP" required="required">
        <span id="otp_error" class="field_error"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group second_box">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="submit_otp()">Submit OTP</button>
    </div>       
</form>
```

Comment: You're calling `submit_otp`, but the function name is `send_otp`..?

Comment: _"But I can't make it run a php file"_ - How did you determine that? Have you checked the browsers console (under development tools) for errors? You can also check the network tab (also in under your browsers development tools) when running your code to see if it makes a request and what it actually returns.

Comment: Seems like #mobile and #email are bound to the send_top function and #otp and #eotp are bound to the submit_otp function. I think you are using the incorrect endpoint or the incorrect function there.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I checked it and it is not making a request to php.

Comment: Could we get a look to that php file as well ?

Comment: `{'mobile='+mobile,'email='+email}` - The `=` should most likely not be there since you're passing the data as json, not as a www-formatted string.

Comment: There is a error saying function not defined.

Comment: Is the functions in the same file in `<script>...</script>` tags or are they in a separate file? If it's in a separate file, are you loading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry folks, it was a simple error.

The corrected part is

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'checkotp.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{'otp':otp,'eotp':eotp},
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the way you're sending your data in your ajax call.
You're sending a string rather than a set of parameters.
Try this syntax :

```
 // code
 type:'post',
 data:{
   'otp':otp,
   'eotp':eotp
 },
 success:function(result){
 //rest of code
```

EDIT : I forgot the quotes on the parameters. It says "function undefined" because it tries to evaluate `otp` as a function while it's just a variable.

Comment: It says function not defined. I am a newbie. I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the format of data you send to the back end 
   as a json format. It binds values related to the given 
   property.

```
function submit_otp(){
var otp=jQuery('#otp').val();
var eotp=jQuery('#eotp').val();
jQuery.ajax({
    url:'checkotp.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{otp: otp, eotp: eotp}, // Declare data in JSON format
    success:function(result){
        if(result=='yes'){
            window.location='savedata.php'
        }
        if(result=='Please enter correct otp.'){
            jQuery('#otp_error').html('Please enter valid otp');
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: `data:{otp: otp, eotp: eotp}, // Declare data as a JSON Object` — There's no JSON there. That's a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

Please use like below code

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url:'sendotp.php',
  type:'POST',
  data:{mobile:mobile,email:email}
  success:function(result){
    console.log(result);
    if(result=='1'){
        jQuery('.second_box').show();
        jQuery('.first_box').hide();
    }
    if(result=='not_exist'){
        jQuery('#email_error').html('Please enter valid mobile or E-mail');
    }
}
});
```